# Git - Move branch name to another branch

Tags: git

Here is the story

1. I got branch named `fts` from remote repo `origin/fts`
2. I've done some commits to local repo `fts` (without pushing)
3. I find I commited something I cannot make public
4. I checkout to last safe commit and get *You are in 'detached HEAD' state.* message
5. I've done new commit.

The logs look like that (without some commits)

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --decorate --all --graph -10
* 3e39eeb (HEAD) That should be pushed as origin/fts
| * f38e892 (fts) That cannot be pushed
|/
* 84fa79a (origin/fts) Commit i got from remote
```

What should I do to

1. Not push commits from current local `fts` (f38e892) to remote.
2. Save this unfortunate branch with different name like `private-fts`
3. Move the branchname `fts` to current detached HEAD (3e39eeb) **without** any rebasing or merging that would incorporate commits from current `fts`.
4. Push current detached HEAD as `fts` (to become `origin/fts`).
5. When I'm sure `private-fts` is not needed, get rid of it from local repo either.

Comment: Is what you can't make public isolated to just one commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you'll want to rename the `fts` branch to `private-fts` using the following command:

```
git branch fts -m private-fts
```

Now, recreate the `fts` branch at `3e39eeb`

```
git checkout 3e39eeb -b fts
```

Push & associate the new `fts` branch to origin:

```
git push --set-upstream origin fts
```

Once you're ready to remove `private-fts` alltogether, do:

```
git branch -D private-fts
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

1. Checkout to `private-fts` from your current `fts` branch. `git checkout -b private-fts`, so all of your current code will be saved in `private-fts` branch.
2. Remove `fts` branch. `git branch -D fts`
3. Switch back to `private-fts` branch.
4. Checkout to your commit, you wish to push to `origin/fts`
5. When you are in detached HEAD, switch to `fts` branch. `git checkout -b fts`

Now all of your needed code will be in `fts` branch, and the unfortunate ones in `private-fts`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset your local `fts` back to what's in `origin/fts` you can do a hard reset to the commit in origin.

```
git reset --hard origin/fts
```